# Does Sonar Rule "Bean Members Should Serialize" still apply with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, sonarqube

The sonar rule

> Bean Members Should Serialize
>
> If a class is a bean, or is referenced by a bean directly or
>   indirectly it needs to be serializable. Member variables need to be
>   marked as transient, static, or have accessor methods in the class.
>   Marking variables as transient is the safest and easiest modification.
>   Accessor methods should follow the Java naming conventions, i.e.if you
>   have a variable foo, you should provide getFoo and setFoo methods.

Stills apply with spring boot?